# Change content of button on hover (JavaFX)

Tags: java, css, javafx

Im looking for a way to set text of a button when "hovered".

```
Logic:

if (button.isHover()){
  button.setText("blabla");
}
```

Either a css solution or code solution is fine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use Bindings or add a listener to the `hoverProperty()` of the button.

**Bindings**

```
button.textProperty().bind(
             Bindings.when(button.hoverProperty())
                     .then("Hovered")
                     .otherwise("Not Hovered"));
```

**Listener**

```
button.hoverProperty().addListener((ov, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue) {
        button.setText("Hovered");
    } else {
        button.setText("Not Hovered");
    }
});
```

**MCVE**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox pane = new VBox();
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Button button = new Button();
        button.textProperty().bind(
            Bindings.when(button.hoverProperty())
                    .then("Hovered")
                    .otherwise("Not Hovered"));
        pane.getChildren().addAll(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 200, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```